# Xcode standard editor shows wrong file (with correct location) while assistant editor shows the correct one

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a project folder, and another projectBackup folder next to it.
Yesterday I was working on my project, and by mistake, I opened another Xcode project, directly realized and closed Xcode.

I reopened my project with Xcode and I can see that all my outlets look disconnected in the standard editor.
I check the location of the open file, and it shows the correct one.
When I open the storyboard and the same viewController in assistant editor, I get the correct one (checked the location) - with the connected outlets.

I removed the content of DerivedData folder - but it didn't help.

What is this bug, how can I fix it?

> *Edit*: Just for info, I did a test : created a new project, copied the folder of the project and pasted it next to it, opened the first
>   one, then the second. Closed both and Boom, outlet connections
>   disapeared (But the application still works)

Comment: The outlets might not look connected, but they probably are. I have come across a similar issue a couple of times myself. Usually it is cause by all files in the project having not yet been indexed, you can tell if this is the case because it will say 'Indexing...' in the top bar.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, It's not indexing, how could I make it start indexing?

Comment: Usually an Xcode restart should kick it into indexing the codebase. Failing that just doing a build with `CMD+B` should fix syntax highlighting and outlet linking icons.

Comment: no, it doesn't help, too easy ;)

Comment: When Xcode gets confused about the location of files (e.g., referencing the same file in a different copy of the project folder), you can use the File Inspector in the Utilities panel to redirect Xcode to the correct location. Steps: select file in Project Navigator, select File Inspector in Utilities panel, see full path to file. If path is to wrong file, click folder icon in File Inspector to open 'Choose File' dialog, select correct file in correct location and click 'Choose' button.